# What photo editing softwares support MacBook Pro's Retina display?

Tags: raw, display, macbook

I just bought a MacBook Pro 15" with Retina Display, after installing Canon Digital Photo Professional on it, I noticed that it does not seem to support Retina mode.

This means that my photos are being displayed at a simulated resolution of 1440 x 900 instead of the native resolution of the screen (2880 x 1800).

I realized that I, along with others, may have to wait for Canon to release an update to support retina displays. However I am not even sure if such update is in their plan for upcoming releases at all.

So I would like to know what pro/enthusiast photo editing software out there supports retina display? Ideally this should be DSLR-oriented, and should be rich in feature that at least matches Canon DPP (Full Raw processing, good workflow, batch processing etc).

iPhoto supports Retina display, while it has some nice little features, I am not sure it is as complete as DPP.

I know that Aperture supports Retina display but I have not used it before and do not know how superior/inferior it is compared to DPP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adobe Photoshop Lightroom does. It has since version 4.3 released on [December 13th, 2012](http://blogs.adobe.com/jnack/2012/12/lightroom-camera-raw-updated-lr-adds-retina-support.html)(it was also in an earlier RC). What are you actually looking for is support of HiDPI, which Lightroom 4.3 and above has. Adobe also updated Photoshop CS6 to version 13.0.2 which supports HiDPI displays. (Note that this does not apply to Photoshop Elements, for which no Retina support is planned.)

If you are interested in Apple Aperture vs. Adobe Lightroom take a look at this previous question: [Apple Aperture or Adobe Lightroom: which is better for post processing RAW photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/apple-aperture-or-adobe-lightroom-which-is-better-for-post-processing-raw-photo)

Adobe Lightroom is superior in almost every aspect to DPP(opinion). For the relative cost to the other photography equipment many own, it is a very reasonable purchase for the benefits. I would recommend testing out the free trial if you have not used it before.

Phase One's Capture One 7 also supports the Retina display. There is a free 60 day trial period.

Comment: I agree, DPP is not really comparable. Back when Lightroom was many hundreds of dollars, I tried to go cheap. But Lightroom is really worth it, IMHO, now that the price is lower. You can sometimes see specials were its under $100.

Comment: @PatFarrell - Exactly! I got the full version of LR4 for $70 in November! No one can pass that up.

Comment: For comparison would you be able to give some comments about DPP vs Aperture? (However I have the impression that Lightroom will be a better choice if you are working with Windows & Mac while Aperture will be better at purely OSX and has better integration with iPhoto)

Comment: @Gapton - You are in luck because that is already covered here: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8640/why-pick-dpp-over-aperture

Comment: Capture One also supports the Retina display. I'm using it on a Retina MPB since Nov. 2012.

Comment: I much prefer DPP to lightroom myself. Ok lightroom is a much better developed piece of software but in terms of the actual end result, IMO DPP, gives pictures with far better colours and tones. In-camera settings and adjustments are preserved meaning that fewer images require adjusting at all, also adjustments are stored in the raw file itself and not in a sidecar file.
Adobe RAW converter does give a little advantage in terms of resolution but unless you view your pictures at actual pixel level, who cares?