# Is it possible to adjust the user interface scaling in Lightroom on high-DPI display?

Tags: lightroom-4

Is it possible to adjust Lightroom 4.4 so the user interface is usable on a 15" UHD (a.k.a 4K) display?

There only appears to be a setting for Font size:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically I don't think you can do what you are trying to do. There are some decent workarounds that you can read about here on a thread about similar functionality in Photoshop(https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1323412).

[Lightroom 4.3 added](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/31237/what-photo-editing-softwares-support-macbook-pros-retina-display) OSX Retina support, then in the 5 Beta Preview they added HiDPI Windows support. This includes automatic scaling of certain aspects. There is no HiDPI setting as it just determines this on it's own as necessary. Because of that I don't think you will find that 4.4 has the option.

Comment: Wow there's some **really** unprofessional responses from Adobe staff throwing stones at Microsoft, whilst still in their own greenhouse...

Comment: Yeah it is odd that the two won't work together on a feature that obviously has great benefits. It is also interesting that Microsoft seemingly doesn't mind Apples huge advantage on this already.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is a Microsoft issue, given there [has been a method to query the physical size, and DPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144877(v=vs.85).aspx) since at least NT4, when I was taught to always query it when studying at University...